# Rcpp/C++/R: Error in comparison DatetimeVector vs. Datetime (error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>')

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Unfortunately, I am not able to make the comparison. When I try to compile, I get the error message:
ambiguous overload for 'operator>' (operand types are 'Rcpp::Datetime' and 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}')

I have attached an example. It is highly simplified and is intended to make the error message reproducible.

Could you please help me to understand what's wrong?

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void identifyValidSignalsTest(DatetimeVector & dtvopen, IntegerVector & ivsignal) {

  Datetime dtv("2000-01-01 00:00:00");
  int n = dtvopen.length();

  // Schleife
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (dtv > dtvopen[i]) {
      ivsignal[i] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just off of reading the error message, it sounds like an issue where you are trying to do the comparison of two different types (date time vs double). What are the types of dtv and dtvopen[i]?

Comment: dtv = Datetime; dtvopen = DatetimeVector; e.g. Posixct like "2000-01-01 00:00:00"

Comment: C++ can be finicky.  We may not having a matching `operator` for `>` between a scalar datetime, and the vector variant.  Worst case, as as a shortcut, you can extract the underlying numeric.  And/or work with the numeric representation of the date,

Comment: @Dirk C++ is new for me. It is my first attempt, as I try to speed up an R functionaliy. Couly you give me a hint/example how to do what you described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

The minimal change: replace `dtv < dtvopen[i]` with `dtv.getFractionalTimestamp() < dtvopen[i]`. If the vector is long, it might make sense to call `dtv.getFractionalTimestamp()` only once and save the result in a `double`.

A more complete solution: Compare `dtv` directly with `dtvopen`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector identifyValidSignalsTest(Rcpp::DatetimeVector & dtvopen) {
    Rcpp::Datetime dtv("2000-01-01 00:00:00");
    return dtv > dtvopen;
}


/***R
dates <- c(Sys.time(), as.POSIXct("1999-01-01"))
identifyValidSignalsTest(dates)
*/
```

Result:

```
> dates <- c(Sys.time(), as.POSIXct("1999-01-01"))

> identifyValidSignalsTest(dates)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Note that I am using a return value instead of the output argument, since this fits the functional style of R better. I am also using explicit logical values instead of implicit ones. It is of course possible to use the logical vector created from `dtv > dtvopen` to create the output value of your original function.

Comment: Good answer. Also, in practice, I sometimes "cheat" as (from R) only send the `as.numeric(myDatetimeVec)` down (and instantiate an `Rcpp::NumericVector` with it) and then compare the `double` values directly.  Similarly, I often accumulate timestamps as vectors of `double` and only type them upon return or once in R.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the issue! BR Joachim

Comment: @Joachim If the answer helped you, also consider "upvotinig" it by clicking on the up-triangle (and good that accepted it).